# View Animation in onResume doesn't work after rotation change

Tags: android

I animate a view in onResume() based on a certain boolean.

```
mView.startAnimation(mAnimation);
```

The animation always starts when returning to the activity, but it never starts when onResume() is called following a screen orientation change. I know that the above line of code is getting called because I checked it with debugging, so the boolean is not the problem.

What's different about an Activity that's coming back from a rotation that would cause an animation not to work?

Comment: Is `mAnimation` a static member?

Comment: Also, you should provide more code. That single line is way out of context.

Comment: It's not a static member. There is not a lot of relevant code to post.  I did just find that if I use a different animation, it works. The Animation I'm using is my own, extended from another Animation. So I'm onto something.

Comment: in your AndroidManifest.xml, do you have `configChanges` include `orientation` or not?

Comment: No, that's irrelevant in this case. Everything else about orientation changes is working correctly. I just figured it out. I'll add the answer, but it's not going to matter to anyone, because the problem was with my extended Animation class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Animation was my own extended Animation that slides a view down by modifying its top margin. To find out the correct distance to slide it, I feed it the height of the view that it's sliding down to reveal.  However, views don't have any height until onResume() is done, so I was inadvertently feeding it an offset of zero.

When returning from other activities, the view tree already has the heights left over from before. But after a screen rotation, the Activity is completely destroyed, so the views don't have any dimensions in onResume().

I fixed it by doing the following:

```
final ViewTreeObserver observer = mObscuredView.getViewTreeObserver();
observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    boolean mDone=false;

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
    if (!mDone){
        mAnimation.setTranslation(mObscuredView.getMeasuredHeight());
        mView.startAnimation(mAnimation);
        mDone=true;
    }
    }
});
```